# asp.net mvc HttpPost call with RedirectToAction is not working. Passing in null model back to HttpGet method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question about `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` methods in ASP.NET MVC.

I have two `HttpGet` method. The `Product()` is first called when entering the page for the first time.
I have a form to submit changes to the database. I want to call the `Products(MyModel updatedmodel)`
with `RedirectToAction` like `RedirectToAction("Products", model)` but it does not call that method. I
have a breakpoint in the overloaded `HttpGet` call but the overload method never gets called.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Products()
{
    // first call 
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Products(MyModel updatedmodel)
{

}
```

The page loads with a form. I hit the select button and it calls the `HttpPost` method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendChanges(MyModel model)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // call database
    MyModel updatedmodel = send
     return RedirectToAction("Products", model);
}

 return View("Products", model);

}
```

Next I changed to only 1 `HttpGet` call with the overloaded model parameter like so. The `RedirectToAction` does call
that 1 `HttpGet` method but the model is null with the `RedirectToAction("Products", model)` call.

Why is the model null if I call with `RedirectToAction("Products", model)` call? How can I fix it?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Products(MyModel updatedmodel)
{

}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendChanges(MyModel model)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // call database
    MyModel updatedmodel = send
     return RedirectToAction("Products", model);
}

 return View("Products", model);

}
```

Comment: Can you verify the form data is in the format you are expecting? What does the browser inspector have for form data on submit?

Comment: So the problem is that when you return from the post method the data displayed in the form are null, right?

Answer (score 1):

Because the overloaded version of the function you are using is

```
RedirectToAction(string actionName, object routeValues)
```

Watch the browser's network requests. `RedirectToAction` returns a 302 Redirect response, prompting the browser to your GET action with `routeValues` sent as query string parameters.

To pass a model directly to the redirected action you will need to use `Session` or `TempData`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendChanges(MyModel model)
{
    ...
    TempData["productData"] = updatedModel;
    return RedirectToAction("Product");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Product()
{
    var model = TempData["productData"] as MyModel;
    return View(model);
}
```

Or you pass an id through the query string and re-query the database.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendChanges(MyModel model)
{
    ...

    // call database
    MyModel updatedmodel = send
    return RedirectToAction("Products", new { id = updatedmodel.Id );
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Product(int id)
{
    var model = db.GetProduct(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

The second method is an extra database query but less code. Also, `TempData` is only available for the next request and reloading `Product` action will no longer have the "productData" instance.